# how to install sqlite3 in electron?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

So here is what i did, i installed electron and sqlite3 inside my project directory

```
npm install electron --save-dev
npm install sqlite3
```

but when i try to run this using `npm start` it gives me error

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
```

this line is inside my main.js where i initialize electron things etc. and it works fine without this line.
here's the error i get.

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module '/home/touseef/Desktop/Projects/pos/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v6.0-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- /home/touseef/Desktop/Projects/pos/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
- /home/touseef/Desktop/Projects/pos/main.js
- /home/touseef/Desktop/Projects/pos/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js
- 
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:627:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/touseef/Desktop/Projects/pos/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:41:16)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/touseef/Desktop/Projects/pos/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
```

My node version is 10.16.3 and i'm running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Just had this issue too. I had to rebuild sqlite3.

Installed [electron-rebuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-rebuild), and added `"scripts": { "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3" },`

to my package.json. Then executed `npm run rebuild`, and let it rebuild. Got rid of this error for me.

Comment: I can't start the app when that rebuild script is included, and then running `$(npm bin)/electron-rebuild` at the end it produces an error, `node-gyp failed to rebuild '/home/resort/Documents/repos/Tagasaurus/node_modules/sqlite3'.`